# Is there a tool on werelate.org to tell your relation to the person on a page?

Tags: werelate.org

Most genealogical programs have a function to tell how I am related to an individual. But this only works for the individuals in my GEDCOM. Some sites, like geni.com, have this on their 'one tree' websites. WeRelate.org is one of the larger, better supported crowd-sourced one-tree sites. Does it have a tool to show how I am related to the person on the page I'm viewing? Or since I'm a living person, just between two pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet. One of the problems is that living people aren't technically a part of WeRelate, since there are no private trees. The WeRelate software isn't aware of where "you" fit into the tree, so there's no way to calculate this.

So, there are a few steps needed before something like this would be possible.